# Is Go good for malware programming

Tags: malware, programming

I read that Golang was used to create malware. Is it good? Will it stay undetected? What will be its performance?

Comment: You usually want to use a lower level language, like C (oh man, I miss the days when C was considered high-level), if you want to do anything fancy and if you want it to be nice and lightweight. Anyway, you can really write malware in whatever language you want, from POSIX shell to GNU Awk to C to COBOL.

Comment: Mallware can be created in any language, would you mind to update your post and put the source of that reading?

Comment: @camp0 it really doesn't matter if the claim is true or not. It does not affect the answer, since malware can be written in any language (even bash scripting)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is it good

Go is a programming language like many others. Malware is developed with system-level languages like C but also higher-level language like Python. Go is something in between - it depends on what exactly the goal (complexity) of the malware is, how much time there is for development, what features the malware should exploit, what skills the developers already have etc.

> will it stay undetected

Go programs will not magically be stealth just because they were written in Go.

> what will be it’s performance??

Runtime is maybe slower than C and faster than Python. Development time is maybe slower than Python and faster than C. It depends a lot on what you actually want to do.